# MDM DeviceLock Payload Error

Tags: php, iphone, json, mdm, payload

After sending the DeviceLock Payload, I get the below error:

```
<Warning>: <APSCourier: 0x1cd51970>: Failed to parse JSON message payload for topic 'com.apple.mgmt.mycomp.mdm': Unexpected end of input while parsing string at line number 1, column 116
```

Comment: You need to supply more context: what MDM system are you using? How was the device enrolled? etc.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the response is not formatted correctly, might be a html page reporting a 404,403 or similar error. I would recommend using a iphone proxy (eg. Charles) and sniff out the call response. This should give you a clear view of what might have gone wrong.

But you will need to provide more information in order to give a better understanding of whats going on.